# Client Certificate on Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: ssl, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, client-certificates

Keeping things simple: I need to add client certificate to a mobile app developed in Titanium but I have no clue about how to start.

I have found no info on the next, except:

- [A reference on Titanium Dev Site](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-securityManager) to a 'securityManager' class, which should finally implement a platform-based method.
- [An HTTPS module for Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Https) but seems to cover only server key pinning, not client certificate.

On the other hand I was trying to find any additional component which speeds up integration of a TLS layer, including the client cert. feature. So far I have found [this](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) but it seems that the HTTP feature is not well documented.

Basically the question is, is there any way to implement client certificates on Titanium Appcelerator? (versions SDK 5.5.0; Studio 4.7.1).

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: stuck in the same spot, did you eventually find anything relevant? the documentation sucks.

Comment: I am sorry @AlbertoM but I wasn't able to implement the whole thing. We finally implemented the server key pinning validation by using the HTTPS module mentioned above. It is worth saying, tough, that now the module has no additional cost for Pro, Team or Enterprise subscriptions (changed recently).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the pinning was not enough in our case, we have a client asking specifically for Certificate Authentication.

I ended up rewriting a whole new http client starting from this module

https://github.com/ioxdue/two-way-authentication/tree/master/HTTPSSLTiModule

The delegate "didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge" only works with NSURLConnection, Titanium used to use that library up to the 3.4.0 SDK but then switched to a different library.